# Swift: Display HTML data in a label or textView

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have some HTML data, which contains headings, paragraphs , images and lists tags.

Is there a way to display this data in one `UITextView` or `UILabel`?

Comment: Use UIWebView instead of UITextView or UILabel. So it will display including images

Comment: Yes I think you are right @TysonVignesh

Comment: @TysonVignesh How can I use UIWebView to display html ?

Comment: @MohamedEzzat see this link https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-load-a-html-string-into-a-wkwebview-or-uiwebview-loadhtmlstring

Answer (score 288, accepted):

For Swift 5:

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you want to put HTML text in a UITextView use:

```
textView.attributedText = htmlText.htmlToAttributedString
```

Comment: This worked great for me, but I had to use label.attributedText instead.

Comment: Great!
I just needed to change encoding data to unicode, for East European Latin letters.

Comment: Great! but label.attributedText should be label.text when calling

Comment: how can i make this function work with quotation marks? currently it's converting single and double quotes into these malformed characters.

Comment: How to give custom font?

Comment: is this supposed to preserve images?

Comment: Thanks, it is working. But How I can change the font size ?

Comment: I am not able to make the href in HTML work when i use this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems to load very slowly

Comment: @Roger Carvalho: Is there a way to set the font-family, -size, etc. for the contained html tags?

Comment: @Muju \n isn't HTML, you'd have to replace that with <br />?

Comment: @BernhardEngl Maybe this could help you along? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412963/swift-change-font-on-an-html-string-that-has-its-own-styles

Comment: hypens are showing as â€‘ is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: @myatmins usually this has something to do with the character encoding of the data. Ensure the source data is in UTF 8 or change the using: parameter to the correct encoding for your content.

Comment: for me, unfortunately, it fails with `Simultaneous accesses to <some memory address>, but modification requires exclusive access`

Comment: @myatmins were you able to fix the "â€‘" issue?

Comment: @MartinzChukz add this in the options `.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue`

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu 
var attributedText = htmlText.htmlToAttributedString
attributedText?.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont(name: "your font name", size: fontSize)!, range: NSMakeRange(0, (attributedText?.length)!))

Comment: I have got a memory leek due to using NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html

Comment: With iOS16 I got log message `UITextView is switching to TextKit 1 compatibility mode because its textStorage contains attributes which are not compatible with TextKit 2.`

Answer (score 37):

Here is a Swift 3 version:

```
private func getHtmlLabel(text: String) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.attributedString = stringFromHtml(string: text)
    return label
}

private func stringFromHtml(string: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        if let d = data {
            let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                                             options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                             documentAttributes: nil)
            return str
        }
    } catch {
    }
    return nil
}
```

I found issues with some of the other answers here and it took me a bit to get this right. I set the line break mode and number of lines so that the label sized appropriately when the HTML spanned multiple lines.

Comment: The HTML's parsed... but incorrectly. The tags no longer appear, but the bold text isn't displayed. I don't know which tags are supported, maybe `<b>` is not.

Comment: Bold tags work fine for me. Can you post your full html that isn't working? Maybe the font you are using doesn't show bold well.

Comment: The html is just text from a CMS editor, encoded to return on a JSON string. The app access the web service, gets the JSON that contains this specific text object - the requirement from the client here is the possibility of adding html tags to the text, similar to a CMS (wordpress) of a website. Maybe I'm encoding the return incorrectly? When I parse the JSON, I print the string return on debug and appears correctly, including the '<b></b>', but on both the emulator and the device for tests, the tags won't work. I'm using Swift 3.

Comment: How can I add custom font?

Answer (score 17):

For Swift 5, it also can load css.

```
extension String {
    public var convertHtmlToNSAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }

    public func convertHtmlToAttributedStringWithCSS(font: UIFont? , csscolor: String , lineheight: Int, csstextalign: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let font = font else {
            return convertHtmlToNSAttributedString
        }
        let modifiedString = "<style>body{font-family: '\(font.fontName)'; font-size:\(font.pointSize)px; color: \(csscolor); line-height: \(lineheight)px; text-align: \(csstextalign); }</style>\(self)";
        guard let data = modifiedString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

After that, go to your string you want to convert to NSAttributedString and place it like the example below:

```
myUILabel.attributedText = "Swift is awesome&#33;&#33;&#33;".convertHtmlToAttributedStringWithCSS(font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16), csscolor: "black", lineheight: 5, csstextalign: "center")
```

[image]
Here’s what every parameter takes:

- font: Add your font as usually do in a UILabel/UITextView, using UIFont with the name of your custom font and the size.
- csscolor: Either add color in HEX format, like "#000000" or use the name of the color, like "black".
- lineheight: It’s the space between the lines when you have multiple lines in a UILabel/UITextView.
- csstextalign: It’s the alignment of the text, the value that you need to add is "left" or "right" or "center" or "justify"

Reference:
https://johncodeos.com/how-to-display-html-in-uitextview-uilabel-with-custom-color-font-etc-in-ios-using-swift/

Comment: is there a way that on clicking "href" and do something ?

Answer (score 16):

Add this extension to convert your html code to a regular string:

```
    extension String {

        var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
            guard
                let data = dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            else { return nil }
            do {
                return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return  nil
            }
        }
        var html2String: String {
            return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
        }
}
```

And then you show your String inside an UITextView Or UILabel

`textView.text = yourString.html2String` or

```
label.text = yourString.html2String
```

Comment: Yes but it only works for text in the HTML. I was also concerned about the images and the lists. Is there any way to display the images and lists is single object??

Comment: @TalhaAhmadKhan you can directly use a UIWebView if you have Images. TextView or labels will not work out as you know.

Answer (score 11):

I had problems to change attributes of text after that, and I could see others asking why...

So best answer is to use extension with NSMutableAttributedString instead:

```
extension String {

 var htmlToAttributedString: NSMutableAttributedString? {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    do {
        return try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
                                      options: [.documentType: NSMutableAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return  nil
    }
 }

}
```

And then you can use it this way:

```
if let labelTextFormatted = text.htmlToAttributedString {
                let textAttributes = [
                    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
                    ] as [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]
                labelTextFormatted.addAttributes(textAttributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: labelTextFormatted.length))
                self.contentText.attributedText = labelTextFormatted
            }
```

Comment: I want to achieve the same but the above code is not working.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5**

```
extension UIColor {
    var hexString: String {
        let components = cgColor.components
        let r: CGFloat = components?[0] ?? 0.0
        let g: CGFloat = components?[1] ?? 0.0
        let b: CGFloat = components?[2] ?? 0.0

        let hexString = String(format: "#%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(Float(r * 255)), lroundf(Float(g * 255)),
                               lroundf(Float(b * 255)))

        return hexString
    }
}
```

```
extension String {
    func htmlAttributed(family: String?, size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
                "html *" +
                "{" +
                "font-size: \(size)pt !important;" +
                "color: #\(color.hexString) !important;" +
                "font-family: \(family ?? "Helvetica"), Helvetica !important;" +
            "}</style> \(self)"

            guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                return nil
            }

            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And final you can create UILabel:

```
func createHtmlLabel(with html: String) -> UILabel {
    let htmlMock = """
    <b>hello</b>, <i>world</i>
    """

    let descriprionLabel = UILabel()
    descriprionLabel.attributedText = htmlMock.htmlAttributed(family: "YourFontFamily", size: 15, color: .red)

    return descriprionLabel
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**See tutorial:**

https://medium.com/@valv0/a-swift-extension-for-string-and-html-8cfb7477a510

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3.0

```
var attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: "<b><i>text</i></b>".data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil)
label.attributedText = attrStr
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm using this:

```
extension UILabel {
    func setHTML(html: String) {
        do {
            let attributedString: NSAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: html.data(using: .utf8)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
            self.attributedText = attributedString
        } catch {
            self.text = html
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good but will only apply to UILabel. It would be much better if it is generic extension which should take html and convert into attributed text.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3

```
extension String {


var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    guard
        let data = data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        else { return nil }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:String.Encoding.utf8], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return  nil
    }
}
var html2String: String {
    return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
 }
}
```

Comment: swift 3.1 NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue

Answer (score 3):

Thx for the above answer here is **Swift 4.2**

```
extension String {

    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard
            let data = self.data(using: .utf8)
            else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [
                NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
                ], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return  nil
        }
    }

    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let label : UILable! = String.stringFromHTML("html String")

func stringFromHTML( string: String?) -> String
    {
        do{
            let str = try NSAttributedString(data:string!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true
                )!, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSNumber(unsignedLong: NSUTF8StringEncoding)], documentAttributes: nil)
            return str.string
        } catch
        {
            print("html error\n",error)
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Yes but it only works for text in the HTML. I was also concerned about the images and the lists. Is there any way to display the images and lists is single object??

Comment: It should be noted that using `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` is _incredibly_ slow [1]. Try and use a library like [DDHTML](https://github.com/dbowen/NSAttributedString-DDHTML) instead.

[1] http://www.robpeck.com/2015/04/nshtmltextdocumenttype-is-slow/

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
extension String {
    func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
        guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
            documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
        return html
    }
}
```

Call:

```
myLabel.attributedText = "myString".htmlAttributedString()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UITextView {
    func setHTMLFromString(htmlText: String) {
        let modifiedFont = String(format:"<span style=\"font-family: '-apple-system', 'HelveticaNeue'; font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>", htmlText)

        let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: modifiedFont.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)

        self.attributedText = attrStr
    }
}
```

Comment: I have got a memory leek due to using NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html

Comment: I've been getting a fatal error when it tries to initialize the NSMutableAttributedString.init. Did someone have the same problem?

<compiler-generated>
specialized @nonobjc NSMutableAttributedString.init(data:options:documentAttributes:)

Answer (score 1):

Display images and text paragraphs is not possible in a `UITextView` or `UILabel`, to this, you must use a `UIWebView`.

Just add the item in the storyboard, link to your code, and call it to load the URL.

**OBJ-C**

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://conecode.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

**Swift**

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com");
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
viewWeb.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

Step by step tutorial.
http://sourcefreeze.com/uiwebview-example-using-swift-in-ios/

Comment: Its possible in both. The string just needs to be encoded properly

Answer (score 1):

If you want HTML, with images and a list, this isn't support by UILabel. However, I've found [YYText](https://github.com/ibireme/YYText) does the trick.

Comment: It's supported if you encode the string properly. There's an attributedString extension for HTML floating around somewhere

Answer (score -1):

IF YOU HAVE A STRING WITH HTML CODE INSIDE YOU CAN USE:

```
extension String {
var utfData: Data? {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)
    }

    var htmlAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.utfData else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [
                                            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
                ], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }

    var htmlString: String {
        return htmlAttributedString?.string ?? self 
    }
}
```

AND IN YOUR CODE YOU USE:

```
label.text = "something".htmlString
```