# NSMutableAttributedString with font size and HTML tag properties

Tags: swift, nsmutableattributedstring

I am having trouble using `NSMutableAttributedString` in order to read a HTML string and increase its font size.

Input HTML: `<b>Lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit <i>amet</i></h3>consectetuer</h3> adipiscing elit`

And `NSMutableAttributedString` is converted as below:

```
let htmlData = input.data(using: .utf8)!

let htmlAttrs = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue] as [String : Any]

do{
    let new = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: htmlAttrs, documentAttributes: nil)

    let tillEnd  = NSRange(location: 0, length: new.length)
    let attr:UIFont   = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)

    //new.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: attr, range: tillEnd)

    textView.attributedText = new
}
```

It reads HTML tags properly and gives output

[image: HTML properly encoded].

But if I want to increase font size and uncomment `addAttribute`, font size is increase but HTML is not rendered.

[image: font size increase but html reading gone]

Can I have attributed string with both font size and HTML rendering?

Comment: That's normal behavior. Italic and Bold are inside the UIFont (and so in NSFontAttributeName). You need to iterate the NSFontAttributeName of your NSAttributedString Here a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41413014/1801544 (Matt answer, but instead of creating a new font like Georgia, use the same one as before).

Comment: Thanks, matt's answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **style** attribute of **span** tag to include CSS with **font-size** property.