# html to AttributedString not changing font size

Tags: ios, swift3, nsattributedstring

I want to **increase** font **size** of `html attributed string`. I also followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412963/swift-change-font-on-an-html-string-that-has-its-own-styles) but still it not working. I am using below code for changing `html string` to `attributed string`.

```
      let strmy = model.strItineraryDescription.html2AttributedString
      lblDescription.attributedText = strmy



extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
           return try NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8), options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue,NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)], documentAttributes:nil)



        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

My `html` **string** like below :-

```
<strong><u>Featured Program</u></strong></p>
\n<ol>
\n  <li>Arrival at Delhi airport. You will receive by our representative.</li>
\n  <li>Driving to Agra and exploring the city.</li>
\n  <li>Back to Hotel for Overnight stay.</li>
\n</ol>
\n<p><strong>City Features</strong></p>
\n<ol>
\n  <li><strong>Visit to Agra Fort \U2013 </strong>Former Name Badalgarh, Shah-Jahan spent his last eight years here. You can watch the mesmerizing view of Taj Mahal from this fort just like Shah Jahan.</li>
\n  <li><strong>Visit to Taj Mahal \U2013</strong> It took 21 years to build and stood in 1653. The palace is considered as the symbol of love. Shah Jahan built this wonder in the memory of his wife Mumtaj Mahal.</li>
\n</ol>
\n<p><strong>(Both Agra Fort and Taj Mahal are UNESCO Declared world heritage site)</strong>
```

Comment: you need to append html tag to existing html string so  see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30711288/3901620

Comment: Thanks for help @KKRocks I have label in `tableviewcell` if i set attributed string as of your suggestion it will change on scrolling .

Comment: no it will not changed on scrolling.

Comment: It will change on scrolling  some time simple text or some time attribute string . @KKRocks

Comment: put code for cellForRowAtindexpath .

Comment: I have put into `cellForRowAtindexpath`@KKRocks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143169/discussion-between-vinod-kumar-and-kkrocks).

Comment: Please share the code you have for `cellForRowAtindexpath`.