# How to set font size on NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

Edit - This has been marked as duplicate, but as I state below, I am looking for a Swift solution.  Everything I've found is written in Objective C.

I am trying to convert HTML into an NSAttributedString, but can't figure how to set the font style and size.  All of the examples are in Objective C which I'm not skilled in.  How can I set the font style/size to System 15 (as an example)

```
private func stringFromHtml(string: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
            if let d = data {
                let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                                                 options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],                                                  documentAttributes: nil)
                return str
            }
        } catch {
        }
        return nil
    }
```

EDIT...... I've tried several ways. I can't get it to work.  I'm now getting an error message: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context. It's pointing to the NSAttributedString
I've tried the following:

```
let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue ]
let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
  if let d = data {
     let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                       attributes: myAttribute,
                       options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: Hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412963/swift-change-font-on-an-html-string-that-has-its-own-styles this one.

Comment: @Larme... I solved it using the extension example in the Link you provided.  Sadly I still don't understand it.  I believe I had to create an NSMutableAttributedString, whereas I was just trying to alter an Attributed String?  Thanks!

Comment: The thing is that attributes works like a dictionary (unicity of key for a given range). Bold, Font, Italic, and Font Size are inside the same one. So you need to iterate to modify one property of the font. The other solution is to modify the HTML before translating it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
let myString = "Swift Attributed String"
let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue ]
let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute) 

// set attributed text on a UILabel
myLabel.attributedText = myAttrString
```

**Font**

```
let myAttribute = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 18.0)! ]
```

**Shadow**

```
let myShadow = NSShadow()
myShadow.shadowBlurRadius = 3
myShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
myShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.gray
let myAttribute = [ NSShadowAttributeName: myShadow ]
```

**Underline**

```
let myAttribute = [ NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue ]
```

**Textcolor**

```
let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue ]
```

**Background Color**

```
let myAttribute = [ NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow ]
```

Comment: What is different from: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/5575752](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/5575752) ? Already suggested that answer in Question comment...please don't duplicate answers.

Comment: if there is similar question ask before you must be provide a duplicate link or comment instead of copy of answer. Thanks

Comment: Yes you! You should! You must! Thanks

Answer (score 26):

In Swift you can use:

```
let stringWithAttribute = NSAttributedString(string: selectedFilter ?? "",
                                             attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])
```

Answer (score 9):

The only thing that worked for me is to wrap the HTML in a `<span>` and apply the style there:

```
let modifiedFontString = "<span style=\"font-family: Lato-Regular; font-size: 14; color: rgb(60, 60, 60)\">" + originalHTMLString + "</span>"
```

Try this extension:

```
extension String {

    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }

    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }

    func convertToAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        let modifiedFontString = "<span style=\"font-family: Lato-Regular; font-size: 14; color: rgb(60, 60, 60)\">" + self + "</span>"
        return modifiedFontString.htmlToAttributedString
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
someLabel.attributedString = someHTMLString.convertToAttributedString()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Please Check this one

```
var attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "labelText", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "system", size: 12)])
label.attributedText = attrString
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this for swift 5:

```
extension String {
    func getAttributedString<T>(_ key: NSAttributedString.Key, value: T) -> NSAttributedString {
       let applyAttribute = [ key: T.self ]
       let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: self, attributes: applyAttribute)
       return attrString
    }
}
```

You can check more attributes styles here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key

**USE**

```
// Background Color
let attributedString = "YOUR_STRING".getAttributedString(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.blue)

// Forground Color
let attributedString = "YOUR_STRING".getAttributedString(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red)

// Font
let attributedString = "YOUR_STRING".getAttributedString(.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15))

// Underline
let attributedString = "YOUR_STRING".getAttributedString(.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single)

// Underline Color
let attributedString = "YOUR_STRING".getAttributedString(.underlineColor, value: UIColor.black)

    
// set attributed text on a UILabel
yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert data to string then use this peice of code

```
let  attributes = [
   NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
            ]
try NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I getting the following error:
Cannot convert value of type [String: NSObject] to expected argument type Autoreleasing unsafe pointer <NSDictionary>  The error is pointing to the attributes variable I added as you suggested.

Comment: which version of swift you are using?

Answer (score 0):

**you can set this way**

```
let attribute: [String : Any] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize, weight: UIFontWeightThin),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red]

let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes: attribute)
```