# How to change NSAttributedString font size

Tags: ios, swift4

How can I change the font size of a `NSAttributedString` that has been initialized with

```
init(data: Data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [:], documentAttributes: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary?>?)
```

Actually I have strings that contain html tags, I use the extension given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048759/swift-display-html-data-in-a-label-or-textview) by Roger Carvalho.
The html tags are correctly rendered but the font is not the same as the regular one given by `FontSizeMetrics`:

```
let fontMetrics: FontSizeMetrics = FontSizeMetrics()
let font = UIFont(name: "NotoSans", size: fontMetrics.fontRegular)
```

Comment: And where do you use `font`? Else you might want to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41413014/1801544

Comment: NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: UIFontWeightLight)

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4:**

`[NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]`