# NSAttributedString setting font size - swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, nsattributedstring

So I am trying to get the following code to work

```
     return try NSAttributedString(data: data, attributes:[ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 18.0) ], options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
```

I have tried the following too but just fails

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {

        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
               let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 72)
               let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,  attributes: attributes, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You convert first into NSAttributedString the HTML code, then you add a font, or you add a HTML tag for that before.

Comment: @Larme the html is only <p> tags and <img/> tags nothing more

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921972/parsing-html-into-nsattributedtext-how-to-set-font https://stackoverflow.com/a/41413014/1801544 etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift- Change font on an HTML string that has its own Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412963/swift-change-font-on-an-html-string-that-has-its-own-styles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are convert html to NSAttributedString?
You can append style to the string source.

example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41519178/4368670

```swift
extension String {
    func htmlToAttributedString(fontName: String = "Chalkduster", fontSize: Float = 72) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let style = "<style>body { font-family: '\(fontName)'; font-size:\(fontSize)px; }</style>"
        guard let data = (self + style).data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    }
}
```

```swift
let html = "<div>content</div>"
lebal.attributedText = html.htmlToAttributedString()
```

result:

[image: result]

Comment: that did not help

Comment: Hi @zhaozq, I am a bit suprised that this is how people are doing this, I would of thought that Apple would of alllowed font re-sizing natively instead of having a complete html style tag

Comment: i think it's difficult to find a range to resize, but using html style tag is easy