# NSAttributedString to HTML in iOS Swift 3

Tags: html, ios, swift

I have searched a lot but can only find HTML to plain text, not the other way around, I have email implementation in my app, thus need to send the content of email as HTML to the backend.

**Edit 1:** I have rich text that includes bold, italic, ordered/unordered list, underlined words.

Comment: what HTML thing are you referring to, will I have to create a function or something to convert it to HTML format.

Comment: `<html><body>YOUR CONTENT HERE</body></html>` Now your text is shown in xml / html.

Comment: @luk2302 actually I have a rich text i.e. bold, italic, ordered/unordered listing etc. I think I should mention this in my question too

Comment: ... which is basically the opposite of plain text. So you are asking how to convert formatted text into html that will look the same as the formatted one.

Comment: @user832 Are you looking for a way to convert `NSAttributedString` to html text?

Comment: @FangmingNing yes i am looking for the same

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to convert `NSAttributedString` to `String`, here is the extension method you are looking for. Simply call `yourAttributtedString.htmlString()` and print it out.

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func htmlString() -> String? {
        let documentAttributes = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
        do {
            let htmlData = try self.data(from: NSMakeRange(0, self.length), documentAttributes:documentAttributes)
            if let htmlString = String(data:htmlData, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8) {
                return htmlString
            }
        }
        catch {}
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to convert NSAttributedString to HTML

Comment: @user832 There is no HTML element in swift. I am converting `NSAttributedString` to a swift `String` object which is html string. When you send email out with this string, you will see it presented as html with your formating stuff

Comment: it isn't detecting formatting like BOLD, ITALIC etc, just converting into HTML with paragraph attribute

Comment: @user832 that's because you haven't added any font yet. Try to set some bold font for your NSAttrbuttedDtring and try again

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048759/swift-display-html-data-in-a-label-or-textview):

```
private func getHtmlLabel(text: String) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.attributedString = stringFromHtml(string: text)
    return label
}

private func stringFromHtml(string: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        if let d = data {
            let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                                             options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                             documentAttributes: nil)
            return str
        }
    } catch { }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what the OP was asking.