# Resizing UILabel with HTML data

Tags: html, ios, swift, swift3, uilabel

I created a UILabel and synced its font size with a seekbar and loaded my html formatted text onto the UILabel. Unfortunately, the format gets removed if I change the font size of my UILabel using seekbar.

I used this approach, from garie, that was answered from another thread

```
private func getHtmlLabel(text: String) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.attributedString = stringFromHtml(string: text)
    return label
}

private func stringFromHtml(string: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        if let d = data {
            let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                                             options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                             documentAttributes: nil)
            return str
        }
    } catch {
    }
    return nil
}
```

Link: [Swift: Display HTML data in a label or textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048759/swift-display-html-data-in-a-label-or-textview)

Is there any approach I could use to retain the my html formatted text?

**EDIT #1:**
This is how I resize my UILabel.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func resizeText(_ sender: UISlider) {
    textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(sender.value) * 20.0)
}
```

The HTML data I'm passing onto my UILabel:

```
<html><body><b>hello world</b></body></html>
```

This is the formatted HTML data on UILabel:

[image]

After resizing the UILabel, it loses its format:

[image]

**EDIT #2:**

Tried Milan's answer but encountered an error. Unresolved identifier in NSAttributedStringKey

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class GalleryViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textLabel.attributedText = stringFromHtml()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func resizeText(_ sender: UISlider) {
        if let attributedText = textLabel.attributedText {
            let newAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
            newAttributedText.setFontSize(newSize: CGFloat(sender.value) * 20.0)
            textLabel.attributedText = newAttributedText
        }
    }


    private func stringFromHtml() -> NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            let string = "<html><body><b>hello world</b></body></html>"
            let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
            if let d = data {
                let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                                                 options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                                 documentAttributes: nil)
                return str
            }
        } catch {
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func setFontSize(newSize: CGFloat) {
        beginEditing()
        self.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length)) { (value, range, stop) in
            if let f = value as? UIFont {
                let newFont = f.withSize(newSize)
                removeAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, range: range)
                addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: newFont, range: range)
            }
        }
        endEditing()
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how you do resize your text in label

Comment: Added code on resizing my UILabel font size.

Comment: try my answer.. haven't tested it, but we will see

Comment: or use a TextView set not to scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the font directly messes up your attributed text. You will have to set font size on the attributedText:

```
@IBAction func resizeText(_ sender: UISlider) {
    if let attributedText = textLabel.attributedText {
        let newAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
        newAttributedText.setFontSize(newSize: CGFloat(sender.value) * 20.0)
        textLabel.attributedText = newAttributedText
    }
}
```

For this to work you will need following extension on `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    func setFontSize(newSize: CGFloat) {
        beginEditing()
        self.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length)) { (value, range, stop) in
            if let f = value as? UIFont {
                let newFont = f.withSize(newSize)
                removeAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, range: range)
                addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: newFont, range: range)
            }
        }
        endEditing()
    }
}
```

Comment: .font in self.enumerateAttribute() says Type string has no member font.

Comment: @PaoloUrielN.Enriquez where did you put that extension?

Comment: Below my GalleryViewController class.

Comment: @PaoloUrielN.Enriquez weird.. try with the updated answer

Comment: It now shows unresolved identifier. Do I need an import for NSAttributedStringKey? Btw, I'm on Swift 3

Comment: @PaoloUrielN.Enriquez Just the `UIKit`.. edit the answer and show there the whole code in that particular file

Comment: @PaoloUrielN.Enriquez based on the rest of the code I guess you are using an older swift version than I do, so just replace `NSAttributedStringKey.font` with `NSFontAttributeName`

Comment: Thank you sir Milan! I'm just new to iOS and apparently found out that it is harder to customize views and layouts here than Android. Good day!

Comment: @PaoloUrielN.Enriquez that depends.. it's a bit harder with attributedStrings, but if you just use `UIFont` with textColor, basic customization is pretty easy.. good luck anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using UserDefaults to save the the NSAttributedString returning from second function:

1- Hold the attributed text in a variable

```
let attributedText = stringFromHtml(string: String)
```

2- Save it in UserDefaults

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(attributedText, forKey: "attributedText")
```

And for retrieving it you may use this format to safely unwrap the value:

```
if let text = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "attributedText") as? NSAttributedString {
   label.attributedString = text
}
```

Comment: But I only wanted to resize my UILabel containing the formatted html text, NOT store it on a local database.

Comment: by using `myLabel.numberOfLines = 0` and `myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping` should resize the label by its contents , but don't set a height to the label