# HTML entities in strings files

Tags: swift, string, nslocalizedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I wan't to customize the font of my strings for exemple I have 2 languages:

"Hello how are you $name ?"

"Bonjour comment vas tu $prenom ?"

Here for exemple I wan't to make :

- "Hello" and "Bonjour" in bold;
- "how" and "comment" in a custom font;
- "are you" and "vas tu" in red;
- and have a parameter to get name.

It is possible to do it in swift? I have created one of the file:

[image]

I tried to put HTML entities:

[image]

How I call it:

```
    let gotham = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "gotham-book", size: 18.0)! ]
    let gothamBold = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "gotham-bold", size: 18.0)! ]

    let gothamOrange = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "gotham-book", size: 18.0)!]

    let accueilTopTextL1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("accueilTopTextL1", comment: ""), attributes: gotham)
    let accueilTopTextL2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("accueilTopTextL2", comment: ""), attributes: gothamBold)
    let accueilTopTextL3 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("accueilTopTextL3", comment: ""), attributes: gotham)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37048759/3151675

Comment: @the4kman but how I use it with NSMutableAttributedString I edited my post

Comment: No solutions ??

Comment: I just linked you one.

Comment: @the4kman I don't see how to use it with strings file