# How to find out how much Visible content is located on a web view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

In my application, I am showing epub HTML files in webview using EPUBLIB. My problem is that I want to use bookmark functionality for my epub reader. For that I want to fetch text from webview which is showing page from my epub's HTML file and then use that text in my bookmark activity to show the user what they have bookmarked. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at HTML parsing - parsing the HTML into a variable in your Swift project.

This link may be helpful: [Swift: Display HTML data in a label or textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048759/swift-display-html-data-in-a-label-or-textview)