# Decoding HTML Special Characters

Tags: html, ios, swift

I am currently working on this app that is integrated to a wordpress website. App Fetches JSON data and displays in TextView.

The am facing a problem with the HTML characters. The Wordpress website adds HTML codes such as `<div><img>` and when it displays in the app it doesn't decode.

Is there a way of decoding HTML characters?

I am currently using below codes:

```
descTextView.text = NewsContentViewController.newsDetail.desc
```

[image]

Comment: Lets make it a bit clear: if you have a desc like: This text is: <a href="./">Some text</a> do you want to have your result as "This text is:" or do you want it as "This text is: Some text"?

Comment: I had the same issues with WP API and html tags. So, I added [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) for converting html to correct (clear) text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: Display HTML data in a label or textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048759/swift-display-html-data-in-a-label-or-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **`NSAttributedString`** like so,

```
let str = NewsContentViewController.newsDetail.desc

if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
        descTextView.attributedText = attrStr
        print(attrStr)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In the above code, do handle if `NewsContentViewController.newsDetail.desc` is `optional String`.

Comment: `if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {` string conversion to utf8 will never fail. You can force unwrap it safely. Note that since Swift 3 `Data` conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` and you can simply pass string utf8 view to its initializer which returns non optional. `let data = Data(str.utf8)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Noted. Thanks 

Comment: Error: Cannot assign value of type 'NSAttributedString' to type 'String?'

Comment: It works without error but this time it cant convert Turkish Characters

Comment: @AslanKayardi Great. Do accept if the answer worked. Happy coding..

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that you are using the correct character encoding in your HTML file. Add the following meta tag to the  section of your HTML file to specify the character encoding:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```