# HTML type text to UILabel takes so too much time to load

Tags: html, ios, swift, time, uilabel

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230632/8351061) works perfectly for converting and displaying HTML type text into UILabel, but for long text it is taking too much time.

Is there any other way or how to improve this?

Comment: Use UITextView instead of UILabel, dont forget to make the textview UnEditable

Comment: Woah, I thought string extension was taking time, but it was UILabel. Thanks @MoayadAlkouz